# MySQL insert INTO a select count

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to insert a select count like this is it possible because It doesn't seems to work.

```
INSERT INTO vote (uid, pid, poid, yes, no, total) 
VALUES (:uid,:pid,:poid,0,0,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM member WHERE pid = :pid2 AND type > 0))
```

Okay well actually this will work. I made a mistake somewhere else. This work.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried to execute it without PDO, just in a MySQL client?

Comment: Do you get a result when executing this subquery? SELECT COUNT(*) FROM member WHERE pid = :pid2 AND type > 0

Comment: I'm good it works I missed a extra bind parameter from a copy past...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO vote (uid, pid, poid, yes, no, total) 
SELECT :uid,:pid,:poid,0,0,COUNT(*) 
FROM member WHERE pid = :pid2 AND type > 0
```

Comment: This should definately work (of all tables and fields exist with the given names), although I expected the other query to work as well.

Comment: thank you actually i had binded one extra parameter... I'm sick that's maybe why I didnt see it. Thank you for your answer thought.